# Skype for Business 2019 and MSPL + managed code not working

Tags: c#, sdk, lync, skype-for-business

I'm using MSPL from Lync SDK to get “sipRequest” and “sipResponse” and we Dispatch the object to our C#.NET project.

I use Microsoft.Rtc.Sip.ServerAgent.dll and I can see the event queue is full. 
I see the MSPL logs in LoggerApi.exe tool but "Dispatch("OnRequest")" function in the "r:splScript" section not firing any event in my C# OnRequest method.

This is working fine with SfB 2015, but not in SfB 2019.

Answer (score 1):

Thank MSFT Developer support I managed to solve it, You need to take the updated ServerAgent.dll from the path: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL\ServerAgent\v4.0_7.0.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\ServerAgent.dll, on Skype server (Front End) and do not forget to upgrade your project to .Net Framework 4.7